# how can I process a file that has different names depending on the folder (in other words get the name first)?

Tags: bash

Let's suppose there is a folder with several subfolders. In each subfolder there is a file, that has a different name depending on the folder. For example

```
basefolder
   |________f1_1_1:  video_1_1_1.mp4
   |________f1_2_1:  video_1_2_1.mp4
   |
   |_ .....
```

I want to write a shell script that do some processing on these files

So I have

```
search_dir=/path/to/the/basefolder/
for entry in "$search_dir"*/
do
    echo "$entry"
    #ls  "$entry"   #<--------HERE

    echo "========================"
done
```

As you can see I can list the subfolders.
I want to do something like

```
process video_1_1_1.mp4 video_1_1_1_out.mp4
```

but the file name varies.
Yes I see that I can perhaps use the `entry` variable to compose the name of the file, but what if the files don't follow this pattern and the only thing I know is that they start with "video"?

Is there a way to get the name of the file in the folder so as to use it later?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this file tree:

```
$ tree /tmp/test
/tmp/test
├── one
│   ├── one-1.mp4
│   ├── one-2.mp4
│   ├── one-3.mp4
│   ├── video-1.mp4
│   └── video-2.mp4
└── two
    ├── two-1.mp4
    ├── two-2.mp4
    ├── two-3.mp4
    ├── video-1.mp4
    └── video-2.mp4

2 directories, 10 files
```

You can use a recursive glob to find all the `.mp4` files in that tree:

```
$ for fn in "/tmp/test/"**/*".mp4"; do echo "$fn"; done
/tmp/test/one/one-1.mp4
/tmp/test/one/one-2.mp4
/tmp/test/one/one-3.mp4
/tmp/test/one/video-1.mp4
/tmp/test/one/video-2.mp4
/tmp/test/two/two-1.mp4
/tmp/test/two/two-2.mp4
/tmp/test/two/two-3.mp4
/tmp/test/two/video-1.mp4
/tmp/test/two/video-2.mp4
```

Or just the ones starting with `video`:

```
$ for fn in "/tmp/test/"**/"video-"*".mp4"; do echo "$fn"; done
/tmp/test/one/video-1.mp4
/tmp/test/one/video-2.mp4
/tmp/test/two/video-1.mp4
/tmp/test/two/video-2.mp4
```

Instead of `echo` you can `process`...

If `process` involves more than one file, you can use `xargs`.

You can also use `find`:

```
$ find "/tmp/test/" -iname "video*.mp4" -type f
/tmp/test//one/video-1.mp4
/tmp/test//one/video-2.mp4
/tmp/test//two/video-1.mp4
/tmp/test//two/video-2.mp4
```

Then you would construct a pipe to `xargs` or use find -exec:

```
$ find [ what ] -print0 | xargs -0 process # xargs way

$ find [ what ] -exec process {} +   # modern find
```